# Solve single Linear Equation w/ Two Variables

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose you have a single linear equation like so:

ax + by + cxy = d

Where x and y are independent variables and a, b, c, and d are constants.

Is there an approach that can be taken to find x and y given just this single equation?

I am interested in integer solutions.

Comment: Warning: This is *not* linear!! Not with the $xy$ there.

Answer (score 0):

If we let $x,y \in \Bbb{R}$, then there are infintely many solutions for this equation. Take any $x \in \Bbb{R}$ value, and calculate $y$ the following way:
$$ax+by+cxy=d \\
y(b+cx)+ax=d \\
y(b+cx)=d-ax \\
y=\frac{d-ax}{b+cx}$$
For example, let $x=1$, then $y=\frac{d-a}{b+c}$.

However, if we need $x,y \in \Bbb{N}^+$, then for an $x \in \Bbb{N}^+$ it's necessary to have $y=\frac{d-ax}{b+cx} \in \Bbb{N}^+$. Assuming that $a,b,c,d \in \Bbb{N}^+$ we need $b+cx\ \vert\ d-ax$, which leads to the following congruency:

$$b+cx \equiv 0 \mod d-ax \\
cx \equiv -b \mod d-ax \\
cx \equiv d-ax-b \mod d-ax \\
(c+a)x \equiv d-b \mod d-ax$$
For an $x \in \Bbb{N}^+$ that solves this congruency, you can use the above formula for $y$ to obtain a solution.

Comment: Awesome :) I worked out y = (d - ax) / (b + cx) but wasn't sure how to proceed from there. I'll give this a go!

Know any good resources on how to solve a linear congruence where x is part of the mod?

Answer (score 0):

If
$ax + by + cxy = d
$
then

$\begin{array}\\
\frac{d}{c}
&=xy+\frac{a}{c}x+\frac{b}{c}y\\
&=xy+\frac{a}{c}x+\frac{b}{c}y+\frac{ab}{c^2}-\frac{ab}{c^2}\\
&=(x+\frac{b}{c})(y+\frac{a}{c})-\frac{ab}{c^2}\\
\text{so}\\
dc
&=(cx+b)(cy+a)-ab\\
\end{array}
$

so that
$(cx+b)(cy+a)
=cd+ab
$.

Let $N = cd+ab$.

For each factorization
$N = uv$,
we want to solve
$cx+b = u, cy+a = v$
or
$x = (u-b)/c, y = (v-a)/c$.

If you want integer solutions
with integer $a, b, c, d$,
this gives enough restrictions
to make finding solutions reasonable.
In particu
we must have
$c | (u-b)$ and
$c | (v-a)$
for each factorization.

If you want real solutions,
we can construct
a one-parameter set of solutions
by setting
$v = N/u$.

Then
$x = (u-b)/c,
y 
= (v-a)/c
= (N/u-a)/c
$
are all the solutions.

Comment: Ha! you worked backwards to my original equation that I'm trying to solve :) 

Given the restrictions c|(u -b) and c|(v - a), how would you use this to effectively find integer solutions?

Comment: For each possible factorization uv = ab+cd, check if c|(u-b) and c|(v-a). If you want positive solutions, you must also have u>b and v>a.